# create sequences for prefix span issue

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to create a list containing sequences in order to call PrefixSpan algorithm. I need a list in this form:

```
 [ [["a", "b"], ["c"]], [["b", "c"], ["d"]], [["c", "d"], ["e"]]]
```

where the 1st two letters of the nested list are the rule/sequence and the single letter is the consequence.

I have data of this form:

```
[[u'a',
  u'b',
  u'c',
  u'd',
  u'e',
  u'f',
],
 [u'a',
  u'b',...]]
```

Applying to this data the following logic:

```
   a1 =[]
    for i in range(len(list2)):
      a2 = list2[i]
      for j in range(len(a2)-2):
        a1.append([a2[j],a2[j+1]])
        a1.append([a2[j+2]])
```

And the result of that has the following form:

```
 [[[u'a', u'b'],
          [u'c'],
          [u'd', u'e'],
          [u'f'],
          [u'g', u'h'],...]]
```

So I can't create this nested two to one tuple sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with list comprehension. I created the following code:

```
a = [[u'a',u'b',u'c',u'd',u'e',u'f'],[u'a2',u'b2',u'c2',u'd2',u'e2',u'f2']]
print([[[v,x[i+1],[x[i+2]]] for i,v in enumerate(x) if i<len(x)-2] for x in a])
```

The output is:

```
[[[u'a', u'b', [u'c']], [u'b', u'c', [u'd']], [u'c', u'd', [u'e']], [u'd', u'e', [u'f']]], [[u'a2', u'b2', [u'c2']], [u'b2', u'c2', [u'd2']], [u'c2', u'd2', [u'e2']], [u'd2', u'e2', [u'f2']]]]
```

I hope this is a idea to solve you problem. For further information you can look up "nested list comprehension".